# P-Channel Switching Circuit

Tags: mosfet, switching, pmos

I want to use an IRF9530 MOSFET and a variable resistor to be able to switch an LED on or off depending on the value of the variable resistor. Eventually I also want to incorporate a MOSFET inverter to switch a different LED on using a ZVP3306 MOSFET when the LED driven by the IRF9530 is off, the LED driven by the ZVP3306 should be on and vice versa. The LED driven by the IRF9530 as shown below is always on no matter what. I'm pretty new to this so any help would be appreciated. [image: IRF9530 MOSFET switch]

Comment: Check out this question on controlling PFETs: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/567982/p-mos-controlled-by-n-mos-via-mcu-resistor-values

Comment: I got the correct values to drive the LED using the IRF9530 and the variable resistor but now having trouble tapping that into the inverter to work properly. Whenever the LED driven by the IRF9530 is off, the Vg for the ZVP3306 is 3.5V which is good but whenever I power on the other LED that voltage only increases whereas is should invert and decrease to turn off the LED

Comment: The voltage at PR1 will change based on what voltage rails are applied and the forward voltage  of the LED.  So it's not a stable circuit as is.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the little diode symbol inside the IRF9530, called the body diode. Since it's drain is connected to ground (0V) and it's source goes to the LED then -12V, then the drain is at a higher potential than the source, so the body diode anode is more positive than it's cathode, so it conducts.

This is why the potentiometer does not affect operation.

You could swap the source and drain pins, which will reverse-bias this body diode, so that the gate voltage actually has influence.

Note that the potentiometer / gate can "switch", but it is not a snap-action behavior. There will be a small range where the LED is dimly lit, according to the pot position. (Every LED also needs a current-limiting resistor.)